# Using .htaccess to drop the template group and part of a Page URI in EE 2?

Tags: expressionengine

Since I first encountered this issue, it has expanded somewhat, as it turns out that rewrites of Page URIs are also affected. As such, I have rewritten my original post to reflect this.

I have recently upgraded my site from EE 1 to EE 2 and it appears to have resulted in some of my .htacess rewrites to change the URL structure no longer working.

My original setup was this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?((403|404|About|Chat|Contact|Copyright|Search)(/.*)?)$ /Westeros/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?((ASoIaF|Digest|Images|Login|Store|Updates|Westeros|member)(/.*)?)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?((403|404|About|Chat|Contact|Copyright|Search)(/.*)?)$ /index.php/Westeros/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?((ASoIaF|Digest|Images|Login|Store|Updates|member)(/.*)?)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

There's a couple of different things going on and some work and some don't, in both of these scenarios.

1) http://www.westeros.org/Updates/ works fine. Updates is a template group.
2) http://www.westeros.org/Search/ does not work. Search is a template within the Westeros template group. It does work to access it as http://www.westeros.org/index.php/Westeros/Search/.
3) http://www.westeros.org/About/ does not work. About is a Page with its URI set to /Westeros/About/. It does work to access it as http://www.westeros.org/index.php/Westeros/About/.

I imagine there's been some internal changes in URL handling between EE 1 and EE 2, but I can't quite grasp how it could stop these rewrites from happening. Isn't a rewrite the first thing that gets done, so shouldn't EE be seeing the rewritten URLs and nothing else? I tested with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and the .htaccess is rewriting the URLs correctly. But EE just doesn't seem to recognize it.

However, judging by the suggestion posted in a comment to use the method provided by Pixel & Tonic, writing out the template group does still work in EE 2. I just can't figure out why my setup doesn't work if his does, nor can I quite figure out how to adapt his example to my situation.

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I've used Brandon's sample here myself for EE2:
http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/making-pt-structure

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, thank you! I will have to experiment with this. :) I am not exactly good at .htaccess, but maybe I can figure out what's different from my approach and work it in.

Comment: I've finally had a chance to study his example, and I don't quite get it. I am not sure why he includes index.php at the start of the statement when the incoming urls won't have it? I am looking at this example: RewriteRule ^index.php/(playa|wygwam|fieldframe|ffmatrix)(/[^\/]+)?(/.+)?$ /index.php/ee$2/$1/$3 [NC,L]